# Is there such a thing as a single dissolution?

Tags: government, australia

In Australia, there is the possibility that we may face a double dissolution in the Federal Parliament because one of the taxes that Tony Abbott promised to abolish was knocked back in the Senate.  I have heard of a double dissolution multiple times, but that got me thinking, does such a thing as a single dissolution (ie only dissolving the Senate or the House of Representatives) exist in Australian politics?

Comment: Dissolving parliament always reminds me of Charles I, which is silly of course, but perhaps whoever answers this could briefly state why it is legal to dissolve parliament at all?

Comment: @RazieMah for instance in Italy the President dissolves it when the Parliment isn't able to vote for a Prime Minister. Obviously elections follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Section 5](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/coaca430/xx5.html) of the Constitution:

> The Governor‑General may appoint such times for holding the sessions of the Parliament as he thinks fit, and may also from time to time, by Proclamation or otherwise, prorogue the Parliament, and may in like manner dissolve the House of Representatives.

As you can see, the Governor-General has the power to dissolve the House of Representatives at any time. This is actually the standard procedure for calling an election - while [section 28](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/coaca430/s28.html) provides that the House of Representatives expires after 3 years, there has only been one instance (in 1910) where the House has actually expired without being dissolved earlier.

There is no similar power in relation to the Senate, apart from when a double dissolution is called under [section 57](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/coaca430/s57.html).

Regular half-Senate elections are held in accordance with [section 13](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/coaca430/s13.html), which provides for Senators to have 6-year terms on 3-year rotations, and that elections must be held within the 12 months before the 3-year rotation date.

More information can be found in [Infosheet No 18](http://www.aph.gov.au/~/media/05%20About%20Parliament/57%20Education%20Resources/571%20Infosheets/PDF/is18.ashx) from the Department of the House of Representatives.